# Meaning of "number of keys in the range $a$ to $b$"

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

Regarding this question:

> You are given an unsorted array $A$ of $n$ integers in the range $2^n −10n \leq A[i] \leq 2^n$.
> Suggest a data structure that allows to answer in $O(1)$ steps the number of keys in the range $a$ to $b$ (note that $a, b$ are not necessarily integers). The construction of data structure should cost at most $O(n)$ steps.
>
> 1. Describe in few sentences the data structure.
> 2. Write a pseudocode for constructing the data structure.
> 3. Write a pseudocode for the `numberKeys(NewDataStructure,a,b)`.
> 4. Give a short explanation of the time and space complexity of (2) and (3).

Can someone please explain me what "the number of keys in the range $a$ to $b$" means?

Comment: *in range $a \to b$* sounds plain enough, but mentioning *key*s without introducing them looks strange. Do *key*s map to *value*s? Are duplicates allowed? `unsorted` and `10n`(+1) should be hints. `construction` may be more straight-forward using more than one iteration/pass.

Comment: (Coincidence on SO: [Suggestion of a Data Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67555435).)

Comment: It probably means "the number of array elements whose value is between $a$ and $b$".

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/140377/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67555435/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means "the number of array elements whose value is between $a$ and $b$".

For the solution, it is crucial that the number of possible values of array elements is $O(1)$.

Comment: I see, so building a BST that holds key values? Something like that?

Comment: That’s an overkill.

Comment: `BST that holds key values` `[is] overkill` in conceptual and implementation effort while meeting *answer in $O(1)$ steps* by plugging $10n$ (or $n$?) $\in O(1)$ - bold.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What do you mean by overkill? Is that good?

Comment: Look it up in the dictionary.